# Turbo cider 3 day fermentation, wonder if it's died?

Tags: fermentation, cider

I made a batch of turbo cider last Sunday (2022/10/02) and it slowly started to ferment over the next three days, peaking at about an inch of foam on top. Please see below for photos.

However I checked today (2022/10/05) and there are no signs of any fermentation (i.e. foam, bubbles in the bin or air lock). My cider was kept in a space with a temperature range of 18C-21C and was undisturbed.

I'm still new to homebrewing and turbo cider so am confused if the fermentation is complete or it's somehow dead. Looking for some insight/guidance please!

Ingredients:

- 3L apple juice
- 1L pomegranate juice
- 250g sugar
- cider yeast
- yeast nutrient

Photos of the fermentation:

- [Day of fermentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l1FXNtrHfgE272xMYByiuOd3lBesIs0g/view?usp=sharing)
- [Two days after fermentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Ej4XhT_h2XxgfXyMK1BHhE9HVwT6cwG/view?usp=sharing)
- [Today, 3 days after fermentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x4qCyuNE6idUe_JwRJVzVTVf2g5RMDwE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Facebook group Turbo Ciders For All.

I took a gravity reading and as it's less than 1.000, so can conclude that it has not finished fermenting. I'll check again in 2 days.